# Restoring agent by importing zip file gives Language " not supported by platform error Dialogflow

Tags: migration, dialogflow-es

I am trying to migrate Dialog flow agents developed on API V1 to V2.
As mentioned on migration steps, i have created a new agent.
Exported existing agent as zip file and now i am trying to restore it on new agent by importing zip file.

However when i restore, i get the error Language " not supported.

Can you please suggest what may be wrong.
I have seen one answer, where in user mentioned Google tech team corrected the agent zip file.

Answer (score 0):

How are you? Same thing happened to me and I manage to correct the error by verifying the json for the intents.  It seems that even though everything works well in DialogFlow, when you export the project, some intents are being exported without its language attribute.  I had to include, in my case "es", to those intents without it. You can also contact support and I think they can do it for you. Mine wasn't to big so I did it myself.  Make sure to validate all your language tags in case you have more responses or voice.

I hope this can help you!! Good day